# Sculpt brushes don't work!

Tags: sculpting

I converted the objects to mesh and remeshed it and then turned to sculpting mode, yet the brushes are not working.
I thought it's my mesh or something else that goes wrong so I added a new torus object to test. But still not working...
(already applied the transforms)
Thank you!

(couldn't upload the file somehow it's 130mb...)
I copied the objects to a new file.
and now the smooth brush works yet it turns out to be like this:

before:
[image]
after:
[image]

what are these weird lines and weird effects...
It doesn't seem to be smoothed out at all...

Comment: Kindly attach a screenshot so we can know better. Also, did you try changing the versions of blender/opening a new file? And are you sure you had selected the right object? A torus has very little geometry so it is hard to view the sculpt results on it.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry hi thanks for reply. I was trying to upload the original file but failed i guess. screenshots attached!

Comment: Check my answer. You have overlapping meshes, delete one of them in object mode as I have stated in my answer.

Comment: right... but the brushes still don't work in the original file which has the whole project in it..

Comment: Just try reopening that file or just press `A` to select all and press `Ctrl` + `C` to copy all and paste into your new file? Check the edits to my answer. If it works consider accepting it.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry thanks!! i just pasted those words to a new file and edited there then pasted it back to the original file..

Comment: If it solved your problem, consider accepting the answer by pressing the checkbox on the left :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the file, but it looks like you have two overlapping objects. Delete one to fix the issue.

Edit: Just try reopening that file or just press `A` to select all and press `Ctrl + C` to copy all and paste (`Ctrl` + `V`) into your new file.